# Automatically transfer child divs from 1st parent div to 2nd parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created two parent `<div>`. Inside the first parent `<div>` I have written a loop,where twenty child `<div>` is getting created. I want at the time of child `<div>` creation, when the height of the first parent `<div>` will get full, then the rest of the child `<div>` will automatically get transferred into the second parent `<div>`.
I failed in every try. I am just sharing my basic codes.

**Css**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
.div2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
.child{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin:1px;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="div1">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        <div class="child">@i</div>
    }
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What kind of templating syntax are you using there in your HTML code? You tagged this `javascript` and `jquery` – are you looking for a solution using those? Or what else?

Comment: @CBroe, yes i want to do it in JS and Jquery.

Comment: **THAT** looks like razor!!!

Comment: @Code I posted an answer 10 mins ago. Did you find it working or not? Please reply?

Comment: @PraveenKumar,yes i am working in mvc4. I just want to implement the view. No use of controller here.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Yes i tried, It is not working.

Comment: You should reply by saying it doesn't work na?

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna use columns? Then use that!

```css
.parent {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
          column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
</div>
```